# JImage - Set generated image quality

Tags: joomla-3.x, jimage

I'm using JImage to generate .jpg image thumbnails.

```
$image = new JImage($image_src);
$resizedImage = $image->cropResize($thumb_width, $thumb_height, true);
$thumb = $resizedImage->toFile(JPATH_BASE.'path/to/photo_thumbnail.jpg', IMAGETYPE_JPEG);
```

How can I set the generated jpg image quality to 70%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument in toFile is the options array, which includes 'quality' as a key. eg.

```
$thumb = $resizedImage->toFile(JPATH_BASE.'path/to/photo_thumbnail.jpg', IMAGETYPE_JPEG, array('quality' => 70));
```

API Doc for Image
https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.Image.Image.html